# How do assembly system calls in FreeBSD on ARM64 machines work?

Tags: assembly, system-calls, freebsd, arm64

I would like to port some assembly code from macOS (M1) to FreeBSD on a Raspberry Pi 4. Since they are both based on ARM64 processors, this should not be too difficult in theory, but I cannot find anything on how to properly execute syscalls in FreeBSD on ARM64 architectures.

Here is my sample HelloWorld program that works fine on macOS,

```
.global _main
.align 4

_main:
    mov     X0, #1          // arg[0] = 1 = STDOUT
    adr     X1, helloworld  // arg[1] = string to print
    mov     X2, #16         // arg[2] = length of our string
    mov     X16, #4         // Unix write system call
    svc     #0x80           // call kernel to output the string

    mov     X0, #0          // use 0 return code
    mov     X16, #1         // Unix exit system call
    svc     #0x80           // call kernel to end program

helloworld:      .ascii  "Hello M1-World!\n"
```

So far, I found out the following changes I need to make to have it run on FreeBSD:

- Change `_main` to `_start`
- Change register X16 to X8 (the register that
  holds the syscall number)

Also, the system call numbers seem to be correct (same as on macOS), judging from the content of `/usr/include/sys/syscall.h`. So that would make it:

```
.global _start
.align 4

_start:
    mov     X0, #1          // arg[0] = 1 = STDOUT
    adr     X1, helloworld  // arg[1] = string to print
    mov     X2, #16         // arg[2] = length of our string
    mov     X8, #4          // Unix write system call
    svc     #0x80           // call kernel to output the string

    mov     X0, #0          // use 0 return code
    mov     X8, #1          // Unix exit system call
    svc     #0x80           // call kernel to end program

helloworld:      .ascii  "Hello M1-World!\n"
```

Then I can assemble and link the program with

```
cc -g -c hello.asm
ld hello.o -o hello
```

and running it in the debugger `gdb` shows that it works until it hits the first `svc` instruction, when it terminates with

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
Illegal operand.
```

So my question is, how do I make this work? More precisely,

1. Is `svc` the correct instruction for a syscall?
2. If so, does it matter what argument we pass for `svc`? (My choice of 0x80 here was arbitrary, as it in fact does not matter on macOS.)
3. What is the calling convention for FreeBSD ARM64 syscalls? (Here, I assumed it is passing the arguments in register X0, X1, X2,... as this is the conventions on macOS or ARM64 Linux.)

Thanks.

Comment: [Apparently](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/master/lib/libc/aarch64/SYS.h) the correct way is `svc 0`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: In general, one way to figure out the ABI basics is to single-step with GDB into a simple libc function like `_exit` or `read`, using `layout asm`, so see what asm instructions actually run.  And look at registers (`layout reg`) before / after the actual system call, and see how the errno check works.